# PHP API working in postman with 200 but 404 in react native axios

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, postman

I am calling an API in react native with axios instance. Some APIs are working fine but there are two APIs which are working in Postman with 200 status code but when calling same with axios giving 404 status code in react native.

Axios instance :

```
import axios from "axios";
import { apiBaseUrl } from "./variables";

export const Axios = axios.create({ baseURL: 'https://aiearn.in/rest_apis/' })
```

```
const fetchTopInvestment = async () => {
        Axios.get('get-top-investment.php')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
                // if (!res.data.error) setPopularProductData(res.data?.data);
            })
            .catch(e => console.log('failed to fetch popular products', e));
    };

useEffect(() => {
        fetchTopInvestment()
    }, []);
```

[image: error]

[image: postman response]

Comment: Make sure you are usin the same endpoints. These are two different requests